# Can someone please solve the following await problem in my Code

Tags: python, python-asyncio, tiktok-api

This is my Code:

```
import os
import requests
import asyncio
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

async def get_sound_download_url(sound_id: str) -> str:
    """Get the download URL for a TikTok sound."""
    api = TikTokApi()
    sound_info = await api.sound(sound_id)
    return sound_info["itemInfo"]["itemStruct"]["music"]["playUrl"]

def download_sound(download_url: str, output_path: str):
    """Download a TikTok sound."""
    response = requests.get(download_url)
    with open(output_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)

async def main(sound_id: str, output_path: str):
    """Main function to download TikTok sound."""
    download_url = await get_sound_download_url(sound_id)
    download_sound(download_url, output_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sound_id = "7210093783109651758"  # Example sound ID
    output_path = os.path.join(".", "sound.mp3")
    asyncio.run(main(sound_id, output_path))
```

I get the following error: TypeError: object Sound can't be used in 'await' expression
[Finished in 794ms]

I tried to solve it but then the id-paramter is not delivered to the Api.

In summary, this Code should give me the sound download-URL with the specified sound_id using the unofficial library TikTokApi. I am hoping, that you can help me out with this problem. I think I have to structure the Code differently but I don't know how. Also please make your answer simple I am in the early stages of programming in Python and I don't understand everything.

Comment: Please post the full error and traceback.

Comment: `api.Sound()` is a class constructor, not an async function. You can't await it.

Comment: It's not a dictionary, you can't index it with `["itemInfo"]`